# DIsplay attribute image if it exists in folder

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, image

I'm adding some information to my product page and I'm not very familiar with php.

Can anyone help me and indicate how can I place these two `echo` in to a valid if. So it should place an image if the image exist's in folder and if it doesn't then put attribute text.

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('gol_marca'); ?>


<?php $brand=$_product->getAttributeText('gol_marca');
      echo '<a href="/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'"><img style="float: right; margin: 2px;" src="/media/catalog/brands/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'.gif" alt="'.$brand.'"></a>'?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have face same problem in one of my project. I have already find the solution for that.

```
<?php
$file= Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/catalog/brands/'.strtolower(preg_replace('`[^~a-z0-9-._]`i', '', $brand)).'.gif';

if(file_exists($file)){
    $merk_file = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/brands/'.strtolower(preg_replace('`[^~a-z0-9-._]`i', '', $brand)).'.gif';
}
else{
  "nothing to do."
}
?>
```

We can check the url based on media folder.

If you facing some problem then let me know.

Comment: Hey, and how should I call the image? Because it doesn't work for me. I have it named Marca_Blanca.jpg

Comment: Have you got image name with extension

Comment: Hey I don't use any extension in this case. I'm uploading the images directly to the folder and then want to add this if, so if the image exist display it and if not, then display text

Comment: you got image name or not?

Comment: yes, I've uploaded the image to media/catalog/brands and it is named Marca_Blanca.jpg. I use this code: `      $file= Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/catalog/brands/'.strtolower(preg_replace('`[^~a-z0-9-._]`i', '', $brand)).'.gif';

      if(file_exists($file)){
       $merk_file = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/brands/'.strtolower(preg_replace('`[^~a-z0-9-._]`i', '', $brand)).'.gif';
      }
      else{
        echo $brand;
      }`

Comment: It doesnt see the image and places the text...

Comment: your all images with .jpg extension or .jpg,.png etc

Comment: I have just provide you logic you have mold this logic as per your system

Comment: I don't get it... something strange is happening... when I change the GIF to JPG it stops working and does not retreive anything...

Comment: you have to trace your code because I already test this code and it will working on my site

Comment: If I copy and paste your code to my view.phtml I get the sytax error: syntax error, unexpected '}', without doing any changes...

Comment: this is code snipet for check image in media folder

Comment: I don't think so this will create problem in that